# Smartmeter report with empty graph and no values

Tags: testing, smartmeter

I want to open report from `.jtl` file in smartmeter app.

To open report in browser i followed this steps:

```
1. Open Smartmeter in create/edit scenario, then right click on workbench.
2. workbench > Add > Non-Test Elements > et@sm - Report Generator.
3. In the Log file(.jtl) field, i selected my generate .jtl file 
4. press graph button to generate report in browser.
```

But the report generated is having changed date and values are changed, graphs also are empty.

Please help [Smartmeter report with changed date and empty graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybUo4.png)

[Empty Graph and no error reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbsrY.png)

Comment: Hi Yoyo, looks like your jtl file is in some kind of unexpected format. Where did you get it? I recommend to send the JTL file directly to SmartMeter.io customer service so they can take a look at it.

Comment: Is your *.jtl file in XML format?

Comment: @ klingac  i cant open this  .jtl file

Answer (score 0):

you are getting it wrong. The trouble is that your are trying to generate report from recording log and not from test results. You did not even run a test apparently. Please follow the basics [here](https://www.smartmeter.io/quick-guide#toc-how-to-record-test-script).

- 1) Record test script
- 2) Run test script
- 3) Get test reports

Regards
Jan

Comment: Thats fine, first time iam able to see result but when i download the result zip file, it saved in ".jtl " format. when i reopen this file again to view result as i described above the values are changed.